# How to filter catalogsearch result collection by custom conditions

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, catalogsearch

I have some product in my magento store and want to filter catalogsearch result collection by some custom condition.

I am using a extra field `date` in magento serach box and I have a custom attribute "available".

If this attribute is set to `no` and selected date is after 5 days then product will not be showing in search result.

For this I have created a custom module and override `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer` `getProductCollection` function.

But how to add these condition to filter `$collection`?